Limit of a function with two variables: $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (1,5)} \frac{\arctan (y-5x)}{\lvert x-1 \rvert +\lvert y-5\rvert}$
I was given the following limit :
$$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (1,5)} \frac{\arctan (y-5x)}{\lvert x-1 \rvert +\lvert y-5\rvert}.$$
I tried to multiply the numerator and the denominator by $(y-5x)$, because I know that the limit of $\frac{\arctan(t)}{t}$ when $t$ approaches $0$ is $1$. but I don't know what to do with the other term, I tried to switch to polar coordinates but it doesn't seem to work as well.
any ideas?
